# Symbol for "greater than and possibly equal"

Tags: notation

How would I say, in mathematical notation that $x$ is greater than or possibly equal to something?
If I was checking an equality, I might suppose it like
$$x \stackrel{?}{=}4$$
Or if I was uncertain of the inequality
$$x \stackrel{?}{>} 4$$
But in my case I know that $x$ is greater than four, but I need to check it as an endpoint. Something like $x\stackrel{?}{\ge}4$ seems to imply that $x$ might be less than four, when in fact I know it is not.

Anyone knows? How do I symbolize "greater than and possibly equal to"?

(I know that I would probably use $>$ and then $\ge$ when I checked it, but I'm wondering if there is a symbol.)

Comment: What exactly is wrong with $x \ge 4$?

Comment: What is wrong with "$\geq$"? And how does $x\stackrel{?}{\ge}4$ seem to imply that $x$ might be less than $4$?

Comment: "Greater than or possibly equal to" i sprecisely what I express using $\ge$

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow : OP seems to read "$\overset{\text{?}}{\geq}$" as "maybe \geq".

Comment: huh? I don't understand why $x \geq 4$ doesn't work.

Comment: How can you "know that $x$ is greater than four" and not know that $x\neq 4$? $x>4$ means that it is not equal to four. There is some confusion about what you actually want this symbol to mean.

Comment: For context, I asked this question while working on an interval of convergence for a Taylor series. I know it converges for $-4<x<4$, but I didn't know if it converges at $x=-4,4$, so I was wondering if there was a different way to symbolize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typically much better to write a sentence than to pretend that assemblages of notation are unambiguously interpretable.  For instance: "Is $x \geq 4$?".  See?  No confusion.

Comment: The first sentence is excellent advice in general. I wish more mathematicians and their students spent time thinking about the clarity of their exposition.

Comment: Yeah, imprecise notation is common in lectures, because the lecturer speaks words over them, and writing on blackboards is slow, but even there is problematic, because students write down the notation, but the not spoken version. As a rule, say what you mean, don't try to shorten everything.

Comment: I agree completely, and that's what I would do. I was just wondering if there was a way to notate that more symbolically, I wasn't planning on using it.